# add margins in html2canvas/jspdf

Tags: html2canvas

I use html2canvas and jspdf to export multi-page Webpage to pdf.  However, there is no margin in the pdf generated.  How can I add margins with html2canvas or jspdf.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    scale: 0.8,
    logging: true,
    allowTaint: false,
    backgroundColor: null
}).then(function(canvas) {
    // Export the canvas to its data URI representation
    var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    console.log('Report Image URL: ' + base64image);

    var imgWidth = 295; 
    var pageHeight = 210;  
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    var heightLeft = imgHeight;    
    var doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4"); // landscape
    var position = 0;

    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();    
    doc.addImage(base64image,'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;

    while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(base64image,'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    }

    doc.save('test.pdf');
});
```

Comment: could you please tell did my answer help?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work if it is multiple pages.  There is no gap between 2 pages.  The following is my modified code:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    scale: 0.8,
    logging: true,
    allowTaint: false,
    backgroundColor: null
}).then(function(canvas) {
    // Export the canvas to its data URI representation
    var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    console.log('Report Image URL: ' + base64image);

    var imgWidth = 295; 
    var pageHeight = 210;  
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    var heightLeft = imgHeight;    
    var doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4"); // landscape
    var position = 0;

    /* addImage explained below:
        param 1 -> image in code format
        param 2 -> type of the image. SVG not supported. needs to be either PNG or JPEG.
        all params are specified in integer
        param 3 -> X axis margin from left
        param 4 -> Y axis margin from top
        param 5 -> width of the image
        param 6 -> height of the image
    */   

    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();    
    doc.addImage(base64image,'JPEG', 10, 10, imgWidth-17, imgHeight);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;

    while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(base64image,'JPEG', 10, position, imgWidth-17, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    }

    doc.save('test.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Is there any way i can add space at the bottom of the first page and at the top of second page?